# 2 class MLP classifier is forced to 1 output (binary classifier)

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I use MLP classifier in python with different kinds of datasets.

When there are more than two classes, I have an equal number of outputs in the classifier. When I have 2 classes, the classifier is forced to 1 output (binary). This messes up the weights matrix as well as the interpretation of the weights.

More specifically, for M input and N outputs the weights matrix (coefs_) is MxN, when N>2. When N=2 the weights matrix is Mx1. Is there any way to force it to two separate classes? What if I want to do Multilabel classification with only two classes?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide a complete example including some sample data and the exact class you're using in sklearn? I suspect you're using [MLPClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html)?

Comment: You may want to use logistic activation functions. in that case, having 2 output neurons is equivalent to having just one (because of the softmax function, the output of the second output neuron will be constrained constrained to be 1- the first). in that setting, binary classification is coherent with multi-class classification.

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys, I sorted it out. 
@JARS, thanks for the hint, I am aware about the softmax vs logistic difference and funnily enough in the MLPClassifier you can't change the output layer activation function as far as I am aware.

Answer (score 0):

Hi and thanks for the reponses. I actually found a solution:

If the labels are one-hot encoded then the classifier with two classes has two outputs.

If the labels are just indices (a vector with integers), there is only one output in case there are two classes. If there are more classes, then it is same as one-hot encoded.

You can check this snippet to see the difference:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
import pandas as pd
noinputs=10
nosamples=300

for noclasses in range(2,4):
    X_train=np.random.rand(nosamples,noinputs)

    Y_train=np.random.random_integers(0,noclasses-1,(nosamples))
    Y_train_onehot=pd.get_dummies(Y_train)

    clf_vector=MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=[],max_iter=2)    
    clf_onehot=MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=[],max_iter=2)    

    clf_vector.fit(X_train, Y_train)
    clf_onehot.fit(X_train, Y_train_onehot)
    print("Number of classes: "+str(noclasses))
    print("Vector labels: Shape of weight matrix: "+str(np.array(clf_vector.coefs_).shape))
    print("One-hot encoded labels: Shape of weight matrix: "+str(np.array(clf_onehot.coefs_).shape))
    print("")
```